# Test passes when run with react-scripts test but fails when run with jest

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

I started my project with create-react-app but have moved to webpack since adding a Django backend.  I haven't changed any of my tests but most of them no longer pass.  Here is an example test which fails

```
it("moving elements to dragAttrCircle and clicking gets to next shape", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}> <ShowShape/></Provider>,{ attachTo: window.domNode });
    wrapper.find('.flipHolder').simulate('click')
    wrapper.find('.flipHolder').simulate('click')
    expect(wrapper.find(Instructions).find('#instructions').text()).to.match(/^Drag the items from the right to the appropriate location on the left Circle/)
    let circleWrapper = wrapper.find(CircleElements)
    let arrowVisibility = circleWrapper.find('.arrows').at(0).find('g').find('line').get(0).props.style
    expect(arrowVisibility).to.have.property('display', 'none');
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(0).simulate("mousedown");
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(0).simulate("mouseup");      
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(1).simulate("mousedown");
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(1).simulate("mouseup");
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(2).simulate("mousedown");
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(2).simulate("mouseup");
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(3).simulate("mousedown");
    circleWrapper.find("Draggable").at(3).simulate("mouseup");
    expect(wrapper.find(Instructions).find('#instructions').text()).to.match(/^click again to see the next shape/)

    let reduxState = wrapper.state().store.getState();
    expect(reduxState.snapReducer.snapped).to.deep.equal([ true, true, true, true ]);})
```

I get the error:

```
ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components
```

But I did not get that error when I was using the create-react-app testing method.  This is how I am currently configuring my tests in package.json

```
"scripts": {"test": "jest",
```

Comment: Try `wrapper.instance().state`, you probably need the component instance to call `state`

Comment: doesn't work, tells me TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null

Comment: Make sense, for functional components (React 16.x) i returns null as per documentation https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html, can you not do `let reduxState = store.getState();` directly

Comment: Thanks, that worked.